# Can I cancel terms when the denominator is involved in addition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $$p(1-q) \over p(1-q) + (1-q)p$$

I know I could cancel $p(1-q)$ from the numerator if the denominator was  $p(1-q) * (1-q)p$. Can I cancel when it is a case like this?

Comment: You have $\frac{r}{r+r}$ for $r=p(1-q)$. So what do you get? Note that $p(1-q)=(1-q)p$ for $p,q\in K$, for a field $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=p, b=(1-q)$ be nonzero.

Then you can commute the denominator's second product as such;

$$\frac{ab}{ab+ba}=\frac{ab}{ab+ab}=\frac{ab}{2ab}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{ab}{ab}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 = \frac{1}{2}$$

Note that you need to be able to isolate a fraction whose value is $1$.  THis is what allows you to cancel factors.  Thus something like

$$\frac{ab}{ab+1}$$

you can not simply cancel the $ab$ term because you can't isolate a fraction $\frac{ab}{ab}$.

Answer (score 1):

As long as $p\neq0,\;q\neq1$, we know that since $p(1-q)+(1-q)p=2p(1-q)$, $$\frac{p(1-q)}{p(1-q)+(1-q)p}=\frac{p(1-q)}{2p(1-q)}=\frac12$$